# Header image not showing in Firefox (still ok with Chrome and Safari)

Tags: css, image, firefox, background

My site's header image and menu background image do not show in Firefox.
I can have them show up in Firebug if I remove the double quotes in url(image_url).

Everything looks fine in Chrome and Safari (as well as on Safari iOS).

http://www.label-inconnu.com

Many thanks in advance for your kind assistance.

Benoît

Comment: Show what you're trying.

Comment: Seems to show up when switching from double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: You don't need double quotes in a `url()`

Comment: Linking to your page is good, but telling us exactly which url you're trying to use would help even more.

Comment: Try this: 
`background: url("/wp-content/themes/labelinc/images/header.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;`
...make it one line and it is fine.... then again you do have a js error ...check your debugger/js

Comment: There are no quotes in the original code. It is Firefox who adds them whatever you do. If you remove the quotes via Firebug, they come back but the pictures start showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install firebug on firefox. I tried to debug it. Then, under styles of `div.art-header-jpeg` class, I tried to disable-enable the image. It works!

Meaning... It's not your fault. **Report it to firefox.**